# In an organization's database, should there be separate department and job tables?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I am creating the backend of a microservice
that will serve as a tool to see in real time how the company's employees are distributed by projects and what days they have assigned to each one.
The database I have raised looks like this:
[image]

The company has 4 departments (Development, Product, Data Science and Operations), but each department of course has its different positions. For example, in development there is Backend, Frontend, SRE and so on for the other departments. My question is if I should create another table for these positions (That is, between departments and employees), or if I should leave the position as an attribute.
To give a little more context, the company is interested in knowing every day how many employees are assigned to projects according to their position, for example, if I have any free backend developer today. If more context is needed to say, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to model a future possible situation in which an employee is a member of two or more departments, then yes, you may place a bridge table between employee and department. But if that's not a realistic scenario that you see ever coming, it safeguards integrity better to force the one-to-many relationship the way you have it above. Also, I would point out that your model suggests a task can only be assigned to one employee. Are you sure that's what you want? You may need a bridge table between Tasks and Employees to allow a task to be worked on by more than one person.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you very much for replying. In this context, an employee cannot be a member of two or more departments, therefore I will follow your suggestion to leave it as in the image. In that case I have a question, should I set default values in the "Position" attribute? I say this because, as I explained, the company does not need to filter them by department but by their position (such as Backend, Frontend, Data Science, Data engineer), which is why I am afraid that when creating new workers there is not a fixed standard for the possible values and then get complicated when filtering.

Comment: Regarding the tasks, you have made me reconsider it. As I have planned, it would be annoying to have to add the same task for each employee, when surely the leader would really want to assign a task to a part of the team, since the app does not seek to see the details of each task but mainly that the members of the C-LEVEL have a better "global" idea of the company's real time and availability. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Position should be a table also, and key to it from the Employee table. That will guarantee standards. Your front-end will have to select from a list populated from Position and will simply pass in an id. But again, can an employee have only one position, now and ever in the future? If so, position_id should be an attribute in Employee. But if an employee can now or potentially in the future have more than one position, again, you'll need a bridge table (Employee_Positions) to create the many-to-many between them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I made myself understand. Employees can only have one position (Backend or Frontend or DataScience or Data engineer etc) Never two or more positions. What I do need is that when each employee is being created, they are assigned a position from a fixed list of positions (That is, I do not want them to create, for example, a worker with a "Python Developer" position, because we handle it from Backend Dev , Frontend Dev, not "Python developer".

Comment: In that case, position should be a table... or should Position be an employee attribute and receive only a list of possible values (for example with Enum in python). Remember that later I will want to filter things like "How many backend devs are free tomorrow" Thank you very much.

Comment: A table is better. Easier to see and manage/change than a check constraint, and permits you to later add attributes of positions without violating normal form.